# What algorithm can break text up into its component words?

Tags: c#, wpf, algorithm, pdf, text-parsing

I was pleasantly surprised to find how easy it is to use iTextSharp to extract the text from a pdf file. By following [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14170/Extract-Text-from-PDF-in-C-100-NET), I was able to get a pdf file converted to text with this simple code:

```
string pdfFilename = dlg.FileName;
// Show just the file name, without the path
string pdfFileNameOnly = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(pdfFilename);
lblFunnyMammalsFile.Content = pdfFileNameOnly;
string textFilename = String.Format(@"C:\Scrooge\McDuckbilledPlatypus\{0}.txt", pdfFileNameOnly);

PDFParser pdfParser = new PDFParser();
if (!pdfParser.ExtractText(pdfFilename, textFilename))
{
    MessageBox.Show("there was a boo-boo");
}
```

The problem is that the text file generated contains text like this (i.e. it has no spaces):

```
IwaspleasantlysurprisedtofindhoweasyitistouseiTextSharptoextractthetextfromatextfile.
```

Is there an algorithm "out there" that will take text like that and make a best guess as to where the word breaks (AKA "spaces") should go?

Comment: I would say it's better to solve the problem of why your text extraction doesn't include spaces, then trying to hack a solution of a new problem you created for yourself.

Comment: [Watch Peter Norvig take on Word Segmentation in The Unreasonable Effectiveness of Data](http://youtu.be/yvDCzhbjYWs?t=18m10s), to know your answer

Comment: @Gavin: Since I'm using this third party code to do the hard part, I don't have much control over why it's happening this way, nor would I call it a problem I created for myself.

Answer (score 5):

Though I agree with Gavin that there's an easy way to solve this problem in this case but the problem itself is an interesting one.

This would require a heuristic algorithm to solve. I will just explain in a bit on why I think so. But first, I'll explain my algorithm.

Store all the dictionary words in a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). Now take a sentence, and look up in the trie to get to a word. The trie tracks the end of the word. Once you find a word, add a space to it in your sentence. This will work for your sentence. But consider these two examples:

- *He gave me this book*
- *He told me a parable*

For the first example, the above algorithm works fine but for the second example, the algorithm outputs:

*He told me a **par** able*

In order to avoid this, we will need to consider a longest match but if we do that then the output for the first example becomes:

*He gave met his book*.

So we are stuck and hence add heuristics to the algorithm that will be able to judge that grammatically *He gave met his book* doesn't make sense.